# android quiz, how to prevent users to see the questions/answers in SQLite DB?

Tags: android, sqlite

I,m creating a quiz to Android, and my questions and answers are stored in the SQLite DB.
Now I realized that maybe users can browse the db and see all questions and answers from the device if they have the apropriate tools, am I right?
How can I prevent them from users from seeing my data? Is it possible to use a password to access data, or something like that?

Thanks in advance,

João

Comment: Which ill consequences would it have that a user learned the answers?

Comment: For such an application, why go through great lengths to encrypt the answers? This is a quiz application, not a security application. If your users want the answers, they'll more likely find them on the Web. I'd suggest you re-think this before implementing any encryption.

Comment: I guess you guys are right, I'll leave it the way it is right now. thanks

Answer (score 3):

Consider using the [`javax.crypto`](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/crypto/package-summary.html) api. Store your answers in the database as encrypted strings, and then use the encryption key in your app's code to decrypt the data after it's read from the database.

Remember that a determined user *will* find a way to break your encryption (typically by coercing the encryption key out of your app's source code), and there is no such thing as 100% secure when dealing with untrusted parties (i.e. users).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's definitely possible!

You can [encode and decode the data with a key](http://practicalcryptography.com/ciphers/caesar-cipher/). At least, it will be not directly readable.

Each time you write data in your DB, you encode it.
Each time you read it, you decode it.